# individual wsp for each webpart

Tags: 2010, deployment

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and all my project related Visual Webparts are inside that solution and I am doing all this on UAT environment. Now I want to know how can I can build separate WSP file of each webpart and deploy on Production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't it be more appropriate just creating a feature per webpart instead?

But just create a new project per webpart you have.

Comment: Regarding second suggestion you mean instead of 1 project for all webparts i shud create one project for one webpart only? and I didnt get your first suggestion..can you please elaborate?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I mean. You can only have 1 WSP per project, not multiple. Thus you'd have to create 1 project for each webpart.

Regarding my first suggestion; In your project you can create multiple features. By doing this, instead of creating 1 project for each webpart you just create 1 feature for each webpart. This way you keep them all under 1 project and still have the choice of activating them one by one according to your needs.